# Tiki Wiki via AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront, tiki-wiki

I have a Tiki Wiki CMS Groupware site running using AWS CloudFront. AWS CloudFront is serving both the dynamic and static content. The frontend is working fine and is caching files, etc., but loging into the admin interface is not working. When I enter my user / password, the screen just refreshes. The whole site including the login is served via HTTPS.

> \tiki-admin.php* and \tiki-login* use the following behaviors:
>
> Viewer Protocol Policy: HTTP and HTTPS
>
> Allowed HTTP Methods: Get, Head, Options, Put, Post, Patch, Delete
>
> Cached HTTP Methods: UnCheck Options
>
> Forward Headers: All
>
> Object Caching: Custom
>
> Forward Cookies: All
>
> Query String Forwarding and Caching: Forward all, cache based on all
>
> Smooth Streaming: No
>
> Restrict Viewer Access: No
>
> Compress Objects Automatically: Yes

I'm assuming there is an issue with the caching or cookies... something is not allowing the login process to complete...

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you really declare the cache behaviors like `\tiki-admin.php*` with a backslash instead of a forward slash `/`?

Comment: CloudFront has: /tiki-admin.php* and /tiki-login* the typo was in the question and not the actually configuration. Sorry about that...

Comment: It sounds like you need to take a look at the request/response headers.  One possibility might be the origin server incorrectly setting a cookie (trying to) using its own domain instead of the domain the browser sent the request to.  Nothing obviously wrong with this config.